# How to hide URL from bibliography by using a harvard style?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, urls, harvard-style

I want my bibliography without URL fields. After modifying `natbib` here:

```
\newcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \textit{#1}}
```

to

```
\newcommand\harvardurl[1]{}
```

I noticed a blank line where the URL used to be. Modifying the `.bib` file is not an option.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It would be useful if you stated which bibliography style you employ. Is it one of the seven files -- agsm, apsr, dcu, jmr, jphysicsB, kluwer, and nederlands --  of the "harvard"-family of bibliography style files? Separately, do you load the `harvard` package in addition to `natbib`?

Comment: I am a using gsm style file found here: http://www.civil.iitb.ac.in/tvm/2905-natBibUsage/natbibusage/natbibusage.html

No harvard package included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are six styles provided by `harvard` which are compatible with `natbib`.

The command `\harvardurl` only format the style of the url. The output of the url is defined in the used `bst` file.

As an example of one of the six styles I use the file `agsm.bst` to demonstrate the behavior.

The file `agsm.bst` has the following code:

```
FUNCTION {write.url}
{ URL empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "\newline\harvardurl{" URL * "}" * write$ newline$ }
  if$
}
```

If the entry of the url is empty you will get no output. Otherwise you get the output:

```
\newline URL formated with \harvardurl \newline
```

To avoid the output of the url you must modify the `bst` file.

*Please note*: Never change the original `bst` file. Make a copy of the needed `bst` in your working directory and modify this new file.